# Is there a way to prevent \mathchoice from resetting the bounds of its contents (with respect to superscript/subscript placement)?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, bounding-box

I have a series of norm macros that I want to expand to `\left\| ...\right\|` in display math but remain as `\| ... \|` in inline math. Each norm has a subscript unique to the macro:

```
\newcommand {\normbrak} [2]                            % display/inline -aware norm brackets
    {\mathchoice{\left\|#1\right\|_{#2}}{\|#1\|_{#2}}{\|#1\|_{#2}}{\|#1\|_{#2}}}
\newcommand {\inorm}    [1] {\normbrak{#1}{1}}         % 1-norm (nuclear norm)
\newcommand {\iinorm}   [1] {\normbrak{#1}{2}}         % 2-norm (operator norm)
\newcommand {\fronorm}  [1] {\normbrak{#1}{\text{F}}}  % Frobenius norm
\newcommand {\infnorm}  [1] {\normbrak{#1}{\infty}}    % infinity norm
\newcommand {\Linorm}   [1] {\normbrak{#1}{L^1}}       % L1 norm
\newcommand {\Liinorm}  [1] {\normbrak{#1}{L^2}}       % L2 norm
\newcommand {\Linfnorm} [1] {\normbrak{#1}{L^\infty}}  % L-infinity norm
```

In certain places, I wish to write, e.g., `\fronorm{\hat H}^{-1}` to get a superscript on the norm as well. My problem is that `\mathchoice` appears to reset the positioning of superscripts and subscripts, yielding

[image: bad norm superscript]

instead of the proper

[image: good norm superscript]

One possible solution is to rewrite every macro as, e.g.

```
\newcommand {\normbrak} [3] {%
    \mathchoice
        {\left\|#1\right\|_{#2}\IfNoValueF {#3} {\sp{#3}}}
        {\|#1\|_{#2}\IfNoValueF {#3} {\sp{#3}}}
        {\|#1\|_{#2}\IfNoValueF {#3} {\sp{#3}}}
        {\|#1\|_{#2}\IfNoValueF {#3} {\sp{#3}}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\fronorm} {me{^}} {%
    \normbrak{#1}{\text{F}}{#2}%
}
```

but this seems messy and redundant.

Is there a way to stop `\mathchoice` from ratching the bounds of its contents, or a macro other than `\mathchoice` that would work here?

Comment: you could make the superscript an optional argument so `\newcommand {\normbrak} [3][] {...`  then `\fronorm[-1]{\hat H}`

Comment: Btw that image really shows why one shouldn't blindly use left/right.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle *sigh* OK. Was hoping to avoid having to change my markup because there are a lot of these scattered throughout the document, but reality is what it is. Thanks.

Comment: as @daleif indicates your example here would look much better without left/right so an alternative solution would be to simply drop the mathchoice

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The problem is that in other contexts where the norm is used, the argument is, e.g., a fraction, and the expanding braces are needed. I know of no way to get LaTeX to use `\left\| \right\|` when it "looks good" and `\| \|` when it "looks good" except to choose based on whether display math is being used. If I don't have the choice made by the macro itself, then I have to implement at least two versions of each of the seven macros, which smacks of bad design. So I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to absorb the possible superscript before calling `\mathchoice`.

Here's a way to do it, with some fixes:

1. use `\lVert` and `\rVert` instead of `\|` (try `\|-x\|` to see why);
2. use `\mathrm{F}` instead of `\text{F}` (try in a theorem statement to see why).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\normbrak}{mme{^}}{%
  \mathchoice{\makenormbrak{\left}{\right}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
             {\makenormbrak{}{}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
             {\makenormbrak{}{}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
             {\makenormbrak{}{}{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makenormbrak}{mmmmm}{%
  #1\lVert #3 #2\rVert_{#4}\IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
}

\newcommand {\inorm}    [1] {\normbrak{#1}{1}}         % 1-norm (nuclear norm)
\newcommand {\iinorm}   [1] {\normbrak{#1}{2}}         % 2-norm (operator norm)
\newcommand {\fronorm}  [1] {\normbrak{#1}{\mathrm{F}}}% Frobenius norm
\newcommand {\infnorm}  [1] {\normbrak{#1}{\infty}}    % infinity norm
\newcommand {\Linorm}   [1] {\normbrak{#1}{L^1}}       % L1 norm
\newcommand {\Liinorm}  [1] {\normbrak{#1}{L^2}}       % L2 norm
\newcommand {\Linfnorm} [1] {\normbrak{#1}{L^\infty}}  % L-infinity norm

\begin{document}

\[
\fronorm{\hat{H}}^{-1}
\]
\begin{center}% for comparison
$\fronorm{\hat{H}}^{-1}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This image, however, clearly shows why using `\left` and `\right` is very dangerous, because it leads to very oversized delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

To assist anyone facing this same issue:

I came up with a workable, if inelegant solution:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\norm} {som} {%
    \IfBooleanTF {#1} {\left\|#3\right\|} {\|#3\|}%
    \IfNoValueF {#2} {\sb{%
        \str_case:nnF {#2} {
            {F}    {\text F}
            {inf}  {\infty}
            {L1}   {L^1}
            {L2}   {L^2}
            {Linf} {L^\infty}
        }
        {#2}%
    }}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This allows for, e.g., `\norm[F]{\hat H}^{-1}` and `\norm*[L2]{\sum\limits_k a_k}^2` to both work as expected, with the `*` manually invoking the `\left| right\|` version rather than the default `\| \|` version.

Inelegant, since the choice of brackets should ideally be decided automatically by the height of the contents, but... workable.

Thanks to @DavidCarlisle and @daleif for suggestions.

Comment: In this case can scan forward for superscript as well, but is highly difficult (as with other TeX programming tasks). I think embellishment does that?

Comment: Wait actually... in this case you just need to distinguish inline and display math, right? In that case it's actually possible to distinguish without `mathchoice` (e.g. use everydisplay https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389460/250119) – unless you count fraction/superscript as inline https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583752/250119